# Manually Retry Firebase Storage Task (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am observing a `FIRStorageUploadTask` as shown below:

```
currentTask.observeStatus(.Failure) { (snapshot) in
    //How can I restart the upload here?
}
```

In practice, I won't immediately be restarting; I'll present some UI asking if the user would like to retry.